# How can I upload image in local folder laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am new in larval development, I am unable to upload image in local folder and I am getting error getClientOriginalExtension() on null. Even I have added code enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form, but still am getting the error. Can anyone give suggestion how to resolve this issue. I have given below my code.
MyBlade file

```
        ****MyBlade file****

                   <form action="{{ route('register.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8"  >
                      @csrf
                     
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="uname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">User Name</label>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username" required />
                              @if ($errors->has('username'))
                                  <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
                              @endif
                          </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group row{{ $errors->has('image') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Profile Picture</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="image" type="file" class="form-control" name="image">
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

**My Controller File**

```
       if ($request->input('image')!=null){
        $files = $request->input('image');

        $extension = $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filaname = time().','.$extension;
        $files->move('public/image/',$filaname);
       // $post->image= $filaname;
     }
       else{
         return $request;
       }
```

**I am getting err:Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on bool**

Comment: Why are you assigning `$request->hasfile('image')` to `$files`. Even if you meant to compare it, it makes no sense.

Comment: HI Thank you for your response. I have edited my code now, please check now it's going to else condition. Can  you give solution for this issue?

Comment: Just read [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#files)

Comment: I think this - $files = $request->input('image'); - should be $files = $request->file('image'); OR $files = $request->image;

Comment: Yes actually image was uploaded successfully into the local folder but database table stored image name like this "C:\xampp\tmp\php2D22.tmp"

Answer (score 2):

If you use `$request->file('image')` instead of `$request->input('image')` you have fixed the problem. The image will then be moved to the `public/image` folder.

However, if you want to upload the file to the `storage/public` folder, you can use the `storeAs()` method on the $file to store it in the `storage` folder.

```
// Your controller
public function update(Request $request, $postId)
{
    if (! $request->hasFile('image')) {
        return $request;
    }

    // Use file() instead of input()
    $file = $request->file('image');

    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // Note you have a typo in your example, you're using a `,` instead of a `.`
    $filename = time().'.'.$extension;

    // To store (move) the file to the 'public/image' folder, use this:
    $file->move('image', $filename);

    // To store the file to the 'storage/app/public/image' folder, use this:
    $file->storeAs('public/image', $filename);

    // Find your post based on some id
    $post = Post::find($postId);

    // Save the filename to the database on the Post model:
    $post->image = $filename;
    $post->save();
}
```

Hope I helped you with this.